# Python selenium while loop passing despite condition being met

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I created a while loop that should look a the titles of the chrome pages and if they all contain the string 404 the pages refresh and the loop starts again. And if any of the pages does not contain the string 404 then the while loop condition is false and my code just continues.
However the while loop is being passed while I know that the condition is true and all the webpages titles contain the string 404 in them

```
# Open first window and Maximize Window
driver.get(web_link_00)
driver.maximize_window()
web_title_00 = driver.title
print('First Window: ' + web_title_00)
# Open a new window, Switch to the new window
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.get(web_link_15)
web_title_15 = driver.title
print('Second Window: ' + web_title_15)
# Open a new window, Switch to the new window
driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
driver.get(web_link_20)
web_title_20 = driver.title
print('Third Window: ' + web_title_20)

# Checking if listing is live with While Loop
while '404' in (web_title_00, web_title_15, web_title_20):
    print("listing Not Live Yet")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.refresh()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.refresh()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
    driver.refresh()
```

Note:
When I change the while loop to check one condition it executes properly example below
However now its just checking for one condition rather than 3

```
# Checking if listing is live with While Loop
# Before: while '404' in (web_title_00, web_title_15, web_title_20):
while '404' in web_title_00:
    print("listing Not Live Yet")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    driver.refresh()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
    driver.refresh()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
    driver.refresh()
```

Comment: You might want to set the value of the 3 variables again after refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

this condition `if '404' in (.., .., ..):` is for exact match like

```
a = "good title"
b = "404" # change to "bad 404" and it will not work

if '404' in (a,b):
  print('error found")
```

To match contains you need loop to check it one by one, or use `any()` for list comprehension

```
while any('404' in t for t in [web_title_00, web_title_15, web_title_20]):
    print("listing Not Live Yet")
```